# How do I access a configuration variable passed into grails from the commandline

Tags: grails

I am trying to send a variable to my grails app through the command line similar to this:

```
grails -Dmy.build.number=33 prod war ROOT.war
```

I have tried to access it as `grailsApplication.config.my.build.number` but I get an empty map. It seems odd that the variable is defined but not set to what I send.

How do I access the command-line property?

I am planning on putting some of my assets(css,js,images,etc) in cloudfront to act as a cdn. So in my build phase I want to use the build number as a cache buster and set my assets to point to `mycloudfronturl/assets/${buildnumber}/script.js`. If there is a better approach, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("my.build.number");
```

Comment: Can you explain why @jon's approach above does not work? I tried the same, from the documentation I expected it to work like that.